# cocoa textfield disabling doesn't disable the cursor change

Tags: cocoa, cursor, textfield

Hello I have a box with 2 NSTextFields in one row.

Also on specific action a custom semiopaque view appears over these 2 textfields. And then on other action, disappears.

When these texfields are covered with the semiopaque view I want them to become disabled and  my cursor not to change when it comes into the area of any of these textfields. And then I want them to become enabled when my custom view disappears.

I do it using the following commands:

```
[fileNameField setEnabled:NO];
[folderPathField setSelectable:NO];
[folderPathField setEnabled:NO];
```

and

```
[fileNameField setEnabled:YES];
[folderPathField setEnabled:YES];
[folderPathField setSelectable:YES];
```

respectively.

The problem is that one called fileNameField does change correctly: it becomes a bit dimmed and doesn't either get selected or change my cursor when it is over the textfield.

But another one, folderPathField also becomes disabled, it isn't possible to select the text, but it still changes my cursor when it enters it's area.

The only differences between these two textfields are:
1. fileNameField has rounded border and folderPathField has no border.
2. fileNameField has layout set to "Scrolls" and folderPathField - "Truncates".

Does somebody know what can be the reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it to not be editable

```
[textfield SetEditable:NO];
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Actually setSelectible also calls setEditable. If the textfield is not selectible it is also not editable. So if it will be selectable but not editable, it will still change the mouse cursor. And moreover, as I understand, setEnabled should do all the job. If the view is disabled it can't respond to mouse events but it does in my case. How could it be...